# 2d collision response between circles

Tags: math, physics, collision-detection

I'm trying to calculate new velocities for 2 colliding balls, but can't really do that before I solve another problem.

Since in digital world a real collision almost never happens, we will always have a situation where the "colliding" balls overlap.

Imagine there is a 100 balls moving randomly so, if I understand it correctly, the procedure should be as follows:

- Move the balls (`x += vx`; `y+= vy`;)
- Get the lest overlapping (or perfectly colliding) balls
- Move the balls "back in time" to that moment
- Perform collision calculations

If the above is correct, then, how could I move the balls "back in time" to the point of first collision? Known data:

- All coordinates of the balls (`b[i].x`, `b[i].y`)
- Ball `X` and `Y` velocities (`b[i].vx`, `b[i].vy`)
- Distance between lest overlapping balls (`dist`)

Should I just calculate how many percent the `dist` is of the perfect distance to the collision and then simply move back `x` and `y` coordinates by the same amount of percent of `vx` and `vy?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For collisions like these, it's usually easiest to look at it from the reference frame of one of the balls.

Let's say you have `ball1` and `ball2`. These balls have positions `p1` and `p2` respectively, and velocities `v1` and `v2`. Let the relative velocity of `ball1` with respect to  `ball2` be `v1-v2=v`.

We want to know when `||p1-p2||` is less than `||r1||+||r2||`, where `r1` is the vector with a length of the radius of the first ball in the direction towards the second ball, and `r2` is vice-versa.

From `ball2`'s perspective, `ball1` is moving with velocity `v1+v2`. At time `t`, `ball2` is at position `p2+(v1+v2)*t`.

The balls collide when:

```
(p1-(p2+vt)) = (r1+r2)
-(p2+vt) = (r1+r2)-p1
-p2-vt = (r1+r2)-p1
-vt = (r1+r2)-p1+p2
vt = (p1-p2)-(r1+r2)
```

Now since `||a|| = ||b||+||c||` when `a = b+c`, we know that

```
||v||t = ||p1-p2|| - ||r1+r2||
t = (||p1-p2|| - ||r1+r2||)/||v||
```

For example: `p1 = (7,5)` and `p2=(4,1)`, `||r1||=1` and `||r1||=2`, and `v1=(1,2)` and `v2=(-2,-2)` then `v=(3,4)`. The collision happens at:

```
t = (||(3,4)|| - 3)/||(3,4)||
t = (5-3)/(5) = 2/5 = 0.4
```

Now that you have the time of the collision, figuring out where the balls are is easy :-)

edit to put the vectormath into pseudocode:

```
p = p1-p2
v = v1-v2
t = (sqrt(p.x*p.x + p.y*p.y) - (r1+r2)) / sqrt(v.x*v.x + v.y*v.y)
```

Comment: Wow there is way too much math for this late hour. Thank you, i'll have to remember vector math before trying to understand any of this. I'll come back with questions if something goes terribly wrong ;]

Comment: ok, i added pseudocode so you don't have to worry about vector math so much!

Comment: Thank you, i'll try it out as soon as i can.

Comment: Thanks i've managed to adapt your math, but unfortunately, as the other posters said, it's not that easy. I thought i could limit myself by low speeds so that the balls would never fly through each other in one frame but it seems i can't. Your equasions, however, answer my original question so thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Whether your strategy of move-then-collide makes sense depends on what kind of thing you are trying to simulate, and on the trade-off between accuracy and speed. If you are, say, writing a snooker simulator, or Super Monkey Ball, then move-then-collide is probably not good enough, for three reasons.

First, the balls will have the wrong velocities after collision. The differences will be subtle, but will feel wrong to players:

> [image] [image: see text]

On the left, velocities at the end of a time-step when balls are allowed to intersect before collision is detected. On the right: velocities immediately after a collision at the correct time and place.

Second, objects moving fast enough may pass through each other without colliding. Or even if you detect the collision, you may eject the objects in the wrong way, causing some kind of illegal motion. (See tasvideos.org for a [collection of collision bugs](http://tasvideos.org/GameResources/NES/SuperMarioBros.html) in the Super Mario Bros games that are caused by this move-then-eject strategy.)

Third, objects may end up intersecting at the end of your time step, with no room to move them apart (because other objects get in the way). So you end up having to draw the objects in intersecting position, which looks wrong.

In applications where these issues matter, then it's better to determine the point of collision before moving the balls. See [this article of mine](http://garethrees.org/2009/02/17/physics/) for a basic introduction to this collide-then-move approach.

Comment: The graphic isn't right, since the balls on the left are shown *before* the collision has been calculated (don't confuse sim time with real time). Your second point is sound, but your third seems to ignore the fact that the sim will rewind time.

Comment: If you're going to rewind time, you have to rewind time for *all* the balls, otherwise you may find that there's a third ball sitting in the spot where you are expecting the first two balls to collide. (And if you're going to rewind time for all the balls, why bother to wind it forwards in the first place?)

Comment: In general, yes, you have to rewind time for all balls -- although you could probably save some work by rewinding it only for balls involved in conflicts like that. (I assume you're only joking about the "why bother...".)

Comment: No, quite serious. I don't see what it gains you.

Comment: If you take out that step, the simulation goes nowhere. Remember, we're discussing move-then-collide.

Comment: link is dead...

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case of one circle centered at the origin and stationary, and the other moving toward it in, say, the **-x** direction. (You can transform any collision case into this with some simple vector algebra.)

So the position of the center of the second circle is (x,y), where y is constant and x is decreasing. The collision occurs when x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = (r<sub>1</sub> + r<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup>, call that x<sub>crit</sub>. But in the simulation we've gone past that, to some x < x<sub>crit</sub>. So we have to rewind enough time to bring it back to x<sub>crit</sub>, which we can calculate easily since we know x, x<sub>crit</sub> and **v**.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: nevermind, my algorithm for finding the point of collision is incorrect. I'll think about this a bit more.

EDIT2: Ok, sorry about that. Try this:

1. Find out when they collided. Let's call this T seconds ago. This would be T such that the distance between the two balls is equal to the sum of their radii. The equation is ((x1 - v_x1*T)-(x2 - v_x2*T))^2 = r1 + r2
2. Move the balls back time T
3. Continue with the your collision

I'm sorry, I don't know how to format math equations on SO. :S

After going back to the time of collision, you can calculate their new velocities fairly easily using elementary physics. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-_and_three-dimensional