# collision detection between a disk and an vertical rectangle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

this is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/whZ44/8/

what I am trying to do is to detect when the ball hit the top border of a stand.if it does than the new coordinate of the ball should be the coordinate of the stand like the doodle jump game. but it seems like my collision detection function isn't working

```
if (Collision(ball, std4)) {
                            console.log("collision");
                            ball.y = std2.x;
                        }
```

the collision function i am currently using and i don't really know if it work under my conditions :

```
 function Collision(circle, rect) {
            var distX = Math.abs(circle.x - rect.x - rect.w / 2);
            var distY = Math.abs(circle.y - rect.y - rect.h / 2);

            if (distX > (rect.w / 2 + circle.r)) { return false; }
            if (distY > (rect.h / 2 + circle.r)) { return false; }

            if (distX <= (rect.w / 2)) { return true; }
            if (distY <= (rect.h / 2)) { return true; }

            var dx = distX - rect.w / 2;
            var dy = distY - rect.h / 2;
            return (dx * dx + dy * dy <= (circle.r * circle.r));
        }
```

Comment: Why not use a framework with inbuilt canvas and collision detection? I recently tried MelonJS wich would fit your needs, easy generating levels based on tiles, collision detection, moving canvas, ...

Comment: i couldn't find the documentation of creating circles and blocks

Comment: It uses HTML5 canvas: `document.createElement("canvas")` or bitmaps/sprites. http://melonjs.github.io/docs/ http://melonjs.github.io/tutorial/ maps can be created with Tiled - http://www.mapeditor.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you are not too worried about working out how the circle will react afterwards then have you considered using a bounding rectangle for the circle?

This post also talks about circle colission:

[2d collision response between circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459035/2d-collision-response-between-circles)

This article is a nice explanation of 2d physics:

http://devmag.org.za/2009/04/13/basic-collision-detection-in-2d-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

The collision function was ok, you just had some variables name wrong:

```
 if (Collision(ball, std4)) {
                        console.log("collision");
                        ball.y = std2.x;
 }
```

TO

```
 if (Collision(ball, std2)) {
                        console.log("collision");
                        ball.y = std2.y;
 }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/whZ44/9/

For further development you should store all obstacles in an array, as you have to check collisions with them all, not only one.