# Detecting Collisions 2D

Tags: java

I'm doing a project in a simple 2D game, Arkanoid game.

I work almost everything correctly, but I'm stuck in the collision of the ball with the bricks, ie, at the time of the crash, should act like a wall, reversing the direction of the ball.

The problem arises to see if that collision occurs horizontally or vertically, for example if a collision with a brick is on the side, should invest only the X axis direction without altering the Y axis, and vice versa.

I do not get to find the code that checks to me.

```
public void detectCollisionWithBricks() {
    for (int i = 0; i < brickGroup.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < brickGroup[i].length; j++) {                
            if (brickExists[i][j]) {                    
                if (getEllipse().intersects(
                        brickGroup.brick[i][j]
                                .getRectangle())) {
                    incY*=-1;
                    incX*=-1;

                    brickExists[i][j] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code:

```
-brickGroup: bidimensional array of bricks

-brick: class painting a brick in the panel

-brickExist: bidimensional array whit se same size as brickGroup, if false, doesn't paint the brick.

-getEllipse(): returns an Ellipse2D.Double, with the coordinates of the ball.

-getRectangle(): returns an  Rectangle2D.Double, with the coordinates of the brick.

-incX: increases the X position of the ball.

-incY: increases the Y position of the ball.
```

Ask if you do not understand some of the code.

Sorry for my english :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot always invert both dimensions simultaneously:

```
 incY*=-1;
 incX*=-1;
```

You must handle each dimension independently.
Try using vectors, see this: [2d collision response between circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459035/2d-collision-response-between-circles)

In your case it may be simpler, it will depend on the existing value of incX or incY. If incX is non-zero and incY is zero, you are moving horizontally. I would advise not to use 1/-1 but some variable speed and invert it:

```
incY = -incY;
incX = -incX;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend an approach as follows;

Firstly represent the bricks as a 2d array

```
bricks = new int[width][height];
```

Where potentially you can change the size of the grid as needed. By doing this you can check for a collision based on the position of the ball at a given time and means there will not be a time consuming checking loop

```
if (bricks[ballx/brickwidth][bally/brickheight] > 0) {
    //we have a collision
}
```

Next you can check whether it is a horizontal or vertical collision based on the position of the games gridlines with a tolerance

```
if (bricks[ballx/brickwidth][bally/brickheight] > 0) {
    if (ballx % gridwidth < tolerance) {
        incx*=-1;
    }
    if (bally % gridheight < tolerance) {
        incy*=-1;
    }
}
```

This should also handle collisions in corners of bricks

Answer (score 0):

If you measure the angle of the line between the centers of the ball and brick (easy to calculate using `Math.atan2()`), you can use it to determine the direction the ball should move to.

Moreover, this will allow you to change the direction in floating point precision instead of only +1 or -1.